# Store a class to cast to in a variable

Tags: c++, oop, casting

Is it possible to save a class into a variable and later cast an object to said class? I Googled a bit but it appears to be impossible to save a class to a variable by for example pointers.

What I am trying to do is, I have a bunch of entities stored inside an `std::unordered_set`. I would like to upcast those variables to their real identity, like Entity to EntityControlUnit.

To do this I would like to store the real class of the object as a constant in the Entity class. The function or method using the object then get upcast it to that class.

Comment: something with (decltype, result_of, declval) or something maybe? I am no expert but my spidey sense leads there

Comment: further, if you could explain why you'd want to do that, I'm sure someone more experienced can come up with a better way to resolve your problem

Comment: sounds like template metaprogramming or some kind of factory function.  Can we have more details on how you want this to work?  For instance, are all the class structures that you want to cast known beforehand?  Also, this sounds like a bad way to circumvent OOP.  Are you trying to downcast or something?

Comment: @Aggieboy I am trying to upcast. I edited the OP

Comment: @AK4749 I added more information to the OP.

Comment: What would be the point?  What would you be able to accomplish that you can't already?

Comment: just to make sure we are on the same page, by upcast you mean cast a child into the parent.  As in the declaration of `Entity` is `class Entity : public EntityControlUnit`

Comment: if you store a set of Entitys, you should only be expecting to perform Entity operations on it. Otherwise, store pointers and dynamic cast and gracefully handle the failure?

something is inefficient in the design

Comment: @HotLicks I would be able to call its methods and access its fields...

Comment: @Aggieboy I believe it is reversed, as per Binero's clarifying comments. ECU : public Entity

Comment: @AK4749 They are stored as pointers.

Comment: @Binero in that case, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast

Comment: though, to be thorough, you should probably see if you can refactor - storing a set of a base class and expecting derived class specific functionality of the set's members is a sign of inefficient design

Comment: Yeah I think I'm just being dumb. I don't think I need to cast at all... For some reason I thought that if you called a child object's method while it's casted to the parent it'd call the parent method. @AK4749

Comment: Correct. If you have not run into slicing and are careful, and have properly overridden the member functions (see virtual functions), you do not need to cast.

Comment: "I would be able to call its methods and access its fields..." -- You can do that anyway.  You just static cast to the appropriate class.